# Flutter Dio unable to set and use proxy for a web request

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, dio

I am writing a flutter app that sometimes needs to make a request to the same endpoint with different paraemters in succession.

The slow version of this works: I await each response before making the next request, which can take quite a while.  When I try to speed things up by starting each request and collecting the future responses, my ip gets flagged and I am blocked for a several hours.

I have introduced a class that in theory will get ip:ports from https://www.us-proxy.org/ and set the proxy to one of those, then make the request.  The goal being: set proxy > send request > set another proxy > send request > etc.

```
class DioProxiedPostRequest extends AbstractWebRequest {

  DioProxiedPostRequest(super.url, super.headers, super.body);

  @override
  Future<WebResponse> send() async {
    Proxy proxy = await ProxyGetter().getRandomProxy();
    String host = proxy.getHost();
    String port = proxy.getPort();

    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.useProxy("$host:$port");
    dio.useProxy(const bool.hasEnvironment('PROXY_URL') ? const String.fromEnvironment('PROXY_URL') : null);

    Response response = dio.post(url, data: json.encode(body));
    return DioWebResponse(url, response);
  }

}
```

it seems like the proxy is never actually getting set, so it works as if no proxy was ever added.

I've also tried replacing:

```
dio.useProxy("$host:$port");
dio.useProxy(const bool.hasEnvironment('PROXY_URL') ? const String.fromEnvironment('PROXY_URL') : null);
```

with:

```
    (dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
    (client) {
  client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
    return isProxyChecked && Platform.isAndroid;
  };
  client.findProxy = (url) {
    return isProxyChecked ? 'PROXY $proxy' : 'DIRECT';
  };

  client.addProxyCredentials(host, int.parse(port), 'main', credentials);

};
```

The result is the same either way, the proxy isn't getting set and String.fromEnvironment('PROXY_URL') returns empty.

I have tried using proxies several ways, including with the http package directly, but couldn't get the request to even work.  Does anyone have experience successfully setting a proxy and using that to send a request?  I am pretty sure I'm missing something so its not getting set properly.